# How does high side MOSFET on BLDC stay on

Tags: mosfet, brushless-dc-motor

I am confused how a the high side mosfets in this diagram stay on once enabled. When turned on presumably most of the voltage is dropped across the motor coil, and so the voltage across the mosfet will be small.

So the voltage at the source and the voltage at the drain are similar, and assuming I am using the same voltage on the gate and hooked up to drain, does this not now mean that Vgs will not be large enough for the mosfet to switch on?

[image]

Comment: Serach for bootstraping drive, transformer drive and charge pump drive.

Comment: Thanks! so gate driver chips that have feedback from between the two mosfets will drive the gate some amount of volts higher than whatever is on source?

Comment: @ronald_s56 Yes. Rephrased, they float a voltage up to the source and use it to drive the gate. Or they drive the gate relative to the source node, rather than GND. Source followers need not apply.

Comment: The thing to remember is that the bootstrap capacitor's charge will drain away eventually, so you can't just switch SW1 on and leave it. For PWM duty cycles < 100% it'll recharge every PWM cycle; you just can't expect PWM duty cycle of 100% ( = always on) to work.

Comment: @Brian Drummond That's why charge pump drive is sometimes used. There is a great TI pdf about it somwhere.